# How to use brat annotation tool in local area network's other PCs?

Tags: nlp, brat

I want to use [brat](http://brat.nlplab.org/features.html) in local area network's another PC, but I can't do it.

My status is here.

- I can use brat in localhost. e.g `http://localhost:8001`
- I can use brat in localhost via Nginx. e.g. `http://XXX.XXX.XXX/brat/`
- I can't use brat in another PC via Nginx. e.g. `http://XXX.XXX.XXX/brat/`
- I can use other apps in another PC via Nginx. e.g. `http://XXX.XXX.XXX/fooapp/`

And, I can see [index.html](https://github.com/nlplab/brat/blob/52516c03f49574a72b3cc19b111df79f5bd385dd/index.html) of brat in another PC via Nginx.

So. I think brat application failed to solve URL. For example, brat's JavaScript or Python has hardcoded `http://localhost/foo/bar` links.

I want to know about brat's configuration to solve this problem or other solution.

Comment: "brat's JavaScript or Pyhton has hardcorded http:/localhost/foo/bar links": As one of brat developers, I can guarantee that no absolute internal links are present in brat. If you can see `index.html` but you can't use brat, then you need to specify what "can't use" means: do you get an error message? What do you see if you access `XXX.XXX.XXX/brat/ajax.cgi?action=whoami&protocol=1`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  I can't see any error message. But I can see `Redirecting...` message. And, I try `XXX.XXX.XXX/brat/ajax.cgi?action=whoami&protocol=1`, then brat returns `{"action": "whoami", "messages": [], "protocol": 1, "user": null}` json message.

Comment: That is the correct response; it should work. Are there any error messages in JavaScript console when you access index.html?

Comment: I'm sorry. I can solve the problem. I overlooked [brat's supported browser](http://brat.nlplab.org/supported-browsers.html) and I used IE9 on windows 7. So, I can use brat on Chrome.